# How to put an editText below a view, both inside a linear layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to put an editText below the frameLayout. It works when the editText comes before the frameLayout but not after.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--TODO: Move to Fragment to enable hideOnScroll flag-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm expecting the editText to show up after the frameLayout, but it just doesnt show up at all.

Comment: Found the solution. Used layout weight instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use **ConstraintLayout**

here is the code:

```
<ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!--TODO: Move to Fragment to enable hideOnScroll flag-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout">

    </FrameLayout>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText not showing because you have set frameLayout height match parent

Change child LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.journaldev.retrofitintro.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--TODO: Move to Fragment to enable hideOnScroll flag-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edit_query"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_query"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry mate it doesn't work it shows up yeah but I kinda want it to show after/below the Framelayout. Not in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`layout_weight`** for **FrameLayout** and make `layout_height="0dp"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...
    ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   // make this "0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"     // add this 
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

</LinearLayout>
```